# Pooling mx Window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I want to pool mx Window component because it is very complex, and creation is slow. But there is problem when addElement within pooled object is called. So, I suppose visual elements are not created after the line: new myMXWindowsClass()?

How to create custom Window component in background and use it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create custom Window component in background and use it later?

The general concept is to use a Factory class.  A Factory class will create and manage instances of a component.  The Flex Framework even includes a [ClassFactory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ClassFactory.html), although I do not think that does anything other than create them.  You could extend it--or create your own--to keep track of classes used and classes not used.  Then whenever a new instance is requested, check to see if there is an unused one available and provide that.  If not; create one and provide that.

I use a technique like this in the Flextras Calendar to handle the days displayed when changing months or moving between the week, month, and day view.  I also use this technique in my mobile game to handle the BitMapData used to create the game board.

Comment: ClassFactory also does not create complete class with all visual elements... When new instance is created I still got error when addElement is called. addElement in this case is adding a component to   Group which is inside created instance. Do I need to add instance to DisplayList to make addElement work?

Comment: @Nemi I'm not sure what you mean by "Complete class". ClassFactory will create an instance of an object and return it; it is no different than using the new keyword to create a class (Except encapsulated).  However, a UIComponent will not go through it's Lifecycle creation process until it is added to a parent which also has been added to the stage.  Depending on code in the UIComponent, it is likely that visual children are not created until this lifecycle process is complete.  addElement will add something to the DisplayList.  I'm unclear what error your receiving or in what context.

Comment: Thanks. Error is simple, can't addElement to Group which is null (cause it is not yet added to stage..?). So, there is no way of initializing MXML component with all visual elements (for later use) without adding it to stage first?

Comment: @nemi You are correct; you can't call addElement on a Null instance of a group.  To initialize a component without adding it to the stage; you'll have to manually run it through the LifeCycle steps.